# Jquery not running on Rail 6 page the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a jquery function running in a Rails 6 app. the jquery toggles a couple of divs to show or hide them, when the user changes the value in a select dropdown.
The problem I have is that the first time the page is visited the jquery does not run. If I change the field, nothing happens.  If I refresh the page, then the jquery starts working properly.  Am I missing something to enable the jquery to run the first time?

Here's the jquery;

```
 $(function() {
        $("#costing_type").change(function() {
          $("#fixed_cost_div").toggle($("#costing_type").val() == "1");
          $("#markup_percent_div").toggle($("#costing_type").val() == "2");
          return false;
        });
      });
```

It's in a files called test2, that's I've required in the application.js file

```
import 'bootstrap'
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
// require("packs/custom")
// require("packs/posts.js")
require("jquery")
// require("jquery_ujs")
// require("custom/test")
require("custom/test2")
```

layouts/application.html.erb has the javascript tag in it

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c124a87536.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
```

I'm at a loss as to why it's not working the first time.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Make sure your function runs after the page is fully loaded like $(document).ready(function () {// call your stuff here }

Comment: you could also be hitting the problem that `local: true` might sort on loading the page ... although @Grumpy's solution would be great if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using turbolinks. the jquery load event is then not fired on every page change anymore. Use sth like this:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $("#costing_type").change(function() {
    $("#fixed_cost_div").toggle($("#costing_type").val() == "1");
    $("#markup_percent_div").toggle($("#costing_type").val() == "2");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Or remove turbolinks if you don't know what it does.

Comment: Thanks very much, you're right, removing turbolinks has fixed the problem.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct.